# Will keeping all my fans at 100% speed harm my computer?

Tags: windows-8.1, fan, cooling

If I use a program such as SpeedFan to keep my fans at 100% power 24/7, will it harm my computer? I don't care about my *power bill* but if the excess power could harm my computer I would worry. I have a 350 watt power supply so I don't think the excess power usage will harm it. Here's what I think:

**Pros**

- Things it cools off are kept cooler
- Cooler parts = faster computer
- Cooler parts = slower fail rate

**Cons**

- It just *sounds* wrong. I know this sounds dumb but still
- Most fans are designed to do their job already
- I'm either gaming or just browsing the web. Obviously gaming while keeping the fans on can be beneficial but my computer doesn't get very hot while browsing the internet.

Comment: Noisy, sucks more dirty air through the case over the computer's lifetime.

Comment: @FiascoLabs What if I clean the case out? And I don't care about noise.

Comment: It's not a case of cleaning the case out, you just are drawing more dust laden air through the system. There are several cases out there with positive air pressure cooling that have air inlet filtration to prevent this. This is opposed to the negative pressure cooling currently used on most systems where you have the fans expelling the air instead of pulling it in and blowing it through the case. It's easier to filter with positive pressure systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only harm that would come to your computer should be the fans wearing down faster.
If you have an insufficient power supply, this might harm it too, but it really probably won't (I mean, I've never heard of a PC fan drawing enough current that it pushed a PSU over the edge… but anything that has a load could present the possibility if you're already borderline I suppose). And the dirt and dust accumulation would require constant vigilance.

I do run my desktop with the fans on a constant (non-100%) speed, since even under full load it doesn't get particularly warm and I prefer a constant level of noise to a variable one. A few months ago, one started rumbling. I popped the actual fan part out of the center (it was on a sleeve bearing one; ball bearing fans often are assembled differently), cleaned it out, and oiled it, and the rumble went away again. It's not come back yet. So far I think I've had these fans for five or six years.

Really, I would just configure the fan speed in the BIOS if possible (you can on mine, but I built my computer myself. I don't know about OEM motherboards). It's more reliable than some random program on your OS that does whatever the hell it does to keep the fans up.

If you don't know how it's keeping the fans up, could just be making the CPU crunch more numbers and heating it up so the OS reacts, for all I know. It could even just be mining bitcoins for the author. So why run software from more sources than you have to and increase the number of people you have to trust?

So anyway, people who make computers and fans know what they're doing. I wouldn't mess with it, because it wouldn't provide a *noticeable* boost to speed (even if technically the overall speed is 1% higher or whatever).

If it's a laptop, then the same rule applies, although often the OS will provide a power setting to determine if it activates fans or instead down-clocks the CPU more or less aggressively. Windows does (or did as of 7) somewhere in the power management control panel. I believe the Linux kernel has similar sorts of functionality; I can manually set my fan speed on my thinkpad that way in Linux.

Comment: in some cases the thermal subsystem is not very efficient (e.g. laptops) and under heavy load the performance difference can be significant (e.g. 1GHz vs 2GHz).

Answer (score 0):

Most APCI motherboards regulate the fan speeds according to the temperature the CPU or the sensors reach, so the fan doesn't have to be always at 100% (so they don't wear out faster). Maybe you could apply a better thermal compound? Artic Silver 5 works great (it's electrical conductive so be careful with it), I've also heard good opinions on the Artic Cooling MX-4 compound. Also make shure you only apply the necessary amount to the processor, a little bit extra and it may spread out and start **isolating** the heat instead of **dissipating** it to the heat sink.

Answer (score 0):

I RAN A BENCH MARK WITH MY LAP TOP (i5 1155g7) SETTING ON THE TABLE, 3 TIMES, ALOWING IT TO COOL TO ITS LOWEST TEMP BEFORE EACH TEST, RECORED THE SCORES.

User bench mark and Passmark 10.2 (each score got better Ram, CPU, DDR drive and graphics scores.    I also it could be the ddr4 and ssd ran better?
... i dont know if they ran better because the temp or ran better because the cpu ran faster/better longer. Who cares? COLDER if faster!

Next,  I put it on top of a box fan; much better bench score, much better"
"fan was off the deck a few feet setting on the edge of two chairs. Laptop intake vents on the bottom with the lap top setting right on the fan grid.)

at no time did the temps (with or without) the fan exceed 100c. I watched the pkg temp very close on each test.

I read that a test had been run and the pc did just as fast running at 90-95c as it did at 1/2 the temps. as long ast max temp was not reached...  In other words the intel chip would keep full boost frequency as long at the temp not not exceed max.  I'm just here to say that was in NO WAY true, the COLDER I keep the unit the better bench score I would get.
with the box fan starting temp was 21-22c the run room temp 20.6c or 69f
No fan the temp was 35c at start of run.   bottom line IMHO the cooler the temp the faster the performance you will get, the longer the rig will last. the better gaming frame rate you will get.. this is big time on a integrated graphics chip

AMD OR INTEL  I also think the max boost speed is also time limited then steps down  4.5 to 4.3  3.85 etc
I then tried this on my mini pc  Ryzen 7 5800H, same results.
mike4dodge@aol.com

Let me know what you think.

this is what they said.   Intel can run at their maximum Turbo Boost frequency all the way up to 100 °C. While there may be a tiny performance difference between a CPU running at 30 °C and one running at 95 °C, our testing has found that the **difference is miniscule**. In fact, even after running benchmarks dozens of times the difference is so small that it is essentially nonexistent. ( I do not agree )

https://www.techspot.com/article/927-temperature-impact-cpu-performance/

Answer (score -1):

350 watt is low for a PSU running load, which means you'll wear it down. But that depends on the quality of the PSU and the number of fans.

Fans are not that expensive and if they break it's not a catastrophe. PSU's are another matter.

You could run fans independently, **keep the intake and HDD ones running fully** as well as the exhaust ones, these don't have sensors and their speeds could be tied through SpeedFan at most with HDD temps to keep them useful, but that's not really useful overall. HDD's don't heat up based on CPU load, ytou could potentially run high IO load applications while the CPU speeds and its temps remain low, thus not triggering the speeds for these HDD fans.

While **the CPU and other fans you can keep at variable speeds**. The CPU has sensors, that's why you can adjust speeds based on load, which in turn will help you in several ways. Noise will be reduced to only when needed, dust on and wear of CPU fans will be reduced and keeping CPU at a stable temp, not necessarily the lowest temp is healthier. This means a delta temp between idle and load at the lowest possible.

This can be achieved by keeping the CPU under low fan speeds when idling, and at load at high fan speeds, so as the average temp isn't offset too much. This will help interconnects of CPU and other parts not strain themselves from thermal expansion and contraction from the large temperature difference, as opposed to running just one speed and having a large delta temp.

Comment: Between the CPU, dedicated GPU, motherboard chipset, RAM, hard/optical drives (earliest made in 2005), and my current USB & PS/2 devices, my system draws a max of around 185 watts. 350W is fine for low to midrange hardware, though hard to find for sale besides in OEM desktops nowadays. Fans don't typically take much current once spinning. With that said, I agree that if concerned PSU takes priority.

Comment: You don't understand wattage rating. A PSU has a combined wattage for 3.3v, 5v and 12v. The 3.3v line is barely used, 5v can be exaggerated on those 350W PSU's to such extent that the 12v rail which is most commonly used is way underpowered. I had a 500W Xilence PSU, just 260W for 12v rail. After wear, a year or 2, it will stop giving out proper 12v when reaching high loads and cause instability. After I had a 400W Sirtec, it would not power 3 HDD and my 180W system. Right now I have a 650W Seasonic and works as intended with added HDD's and a RX580. Fans use 5-6W of power at max speeds.

Comment: this is fair; I'd ignored the different voltage rails having their own independent ratings. My mistake.